# Update com o SET de outra tabela

Tags: firebird, sql-update

Estou tentando fazer um update com JOIN...

A instrução a seguir, foi só um chute, para passar a ideia do que quero fazer:

```
UPDATE PCPSEQPROC_001  PCPSEQPROC 
SET 
    PCPSEQPROC.ID_PCPSEQPROC = PCPSEQ.ID_PCPSEQ
    INNER JOIN PCPSEQ_001 PCPSEQ ON PCPSEQ.PRODUTO = PCPSEQPROC.PRODUTO
WHERE PCPSEQPROC.ID_PCPSEQPROC IS NULL
```

**Edit**

Consulta deve ser realizada no Firebird.

Comment: Em qual banco? MySQL? Postgres? MSSQL?

Comment: Se for MySQL a sintaxe está incorreta, o `SET` vem após o `INNER JOIN`

Comment: gbd é o firebird

Answer (score 1):

Tente desta forma:

```
UPDATE PCPSEQPROC_001
SET 
    PCPSEQPROC.ID_PCPSEQPROC = PCPSEQ.ID_PCPSEQ
FROM PCPSEQPROC_001 AS PCPSEQPROC
    INNER JOIN PCPSEQ_001 PCPSEQ ON PCPSEQ.PRODUTO = PCPSEQPROC.PRODUTO
WHERE PCPSEQPROC.ID_PCPSEQPROC IS NULL
```

**Edit**
Firebird:

```
UPDATE PCPSEQPROC_001
SET 
    PCPSEQPROC.ID_PCPSEQPROC = (SELECT PCPSEQ.ID_PCPSEQ FROM PCPSEQPROC_001 AS PCPSEQPROC
    INNER JOIN PCPSEQ_001 PCPSEQ ON PCPSEQ.PRODUTO = PCPSEQPROC.PRODUTO
WHERE PCPSEQPROC.ID_PCPSEQPROC IS NULL)
```

Comment: Não tem select para ter "from", da erro!

Comment: Você não tinha deixado explícito o seu banco quando respondi. Veja este link e vê se te ajuda. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pt-BR/9304439c-b413-4c1f-ae1a-e282439b8c5a/update-no-firebird-com-mais-de-uma-tabela-como-fazer?forum=vscsharppt&forum=vscsharppt

Comment: com sub-select, da ambiguous multiple rows,

Comment: O seu select, retorna apenas um registro ou mais? Deve retornar um só

Answer (score 1):

Tenta desta forma é um update com  select correlacionnado ( correlated select )... algo assim:

```
UPDATE PCPSEQPROC_001  PCPSEQPROC 
SET 
   PCPSEQPROC.ID_PCPSEQPROC = (select PCPSEQ.ID_PCPSEQ from
       PCPSEQ_001 PCPSEQ where PCPSEQ.PRODUTO = PCPSEQPROC.PRODUTO)
WHERE PCPSEQPROC.ID_PCPSEQPROC IS NULL
```

Se der ambigous no subselect, vocë tem mais de uma chave, não é um para um o relacionamento de PCPSEQPROC e PCPSEQ_001, neste caso, Vocë precisaria de algo como a seguir para recuperar uma única linha no subselect, mas tenha certeza que é isto que vc quer!!!

```
UPDATE PCPSEQPROC_001  PCPSEQPROC 
SET 
   PCPSEQPROC.ID_PCPSEQPROC = (select MIN(PCPSEQ.ID_PCPSEQ) from
       PCPSEQ_001 PCPSEQ where PCPSEQ.PRODUTO = PCPSEQPROC.PRODUTO)
WHERE PCPSEQPROC.ID_PCPSEQPROC IS NULL
```

não tenho banco para testar mas é mais ou menos isto!